# How to set Default value on search form?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, default-value

I'm using a wordpress real estate plugin for my project which is wpcasa, I already do some modification, But this thing takes my time to figure out.

I think they use array to get set values/labels on search form.
Anyone can Help me to how to add default value into a search form?

Here's the code below

```
$defaults = array(          
            'keyword' => array(
                'label'         => __( 'Keyword or Listing ID', 'wpcasa' ) . '&hellip;',
                'type'          => 'text',
                'class'         => 'width-3-4',
                'priority'      => 10
            ),          
            'submit' => array(
                'label'         => __( 'Search', 'wpcasa' ),
                'type'          => 'submit',
                'class'         => 'width-1-4',
                'priority'      => 20
            ),
            'offer' => array(
                'label'         => __( 'Offer', 'wpcasa' ),
                'key'           => '_price_offer',
                'data'          => wpsight_offers(),
                'type'          => 'select',
                'data_compare'  => '=',
                'class'         => 'width-1-5',
                'priority'      => 30
            ),
            'location' => array(
                'data'          => array(
                    // wp_dropdown_categories() options
                    'taxonomy'          => 'location',
                    'show_option_none'  => __( 'Location', 'wpcasa' ),
                    'option_none_value' => '',
                    'hierarchical'      => 1,
                    'orderby'           => 'ID',
                    'order'             => 'ASC'
                ),
                'type'          => 'taxonomy_select',
                'class'         => 'width-1-5',
                'priority'      => 40
            ),
            'listing-type' => array(
                'data'          => array(
                    // wp_dropdown_categories() options
                    'taxonomy'          => 'listing-type',
                    'show_option_none'  => __( 'Type', 'wpcasa' ),
                    'option_none_value' => '',
                    'hierarchical'      => 1,
                    'orderby'           => 'ID', 
                    'order'             => 'ASC'
                ),
                'type'          => 'taxonomy_select',
                'class'         => 'width-1-5',
                'priority'      => 50
            ),
            $details['details_1']['id'] => array(
                'label'         => $details['details_1']['label'],
                'key'           => '_details_1',
                'data'          => $details['details_1']['data'],
                'type'          => 'select',
                'data_compare'  => '>=',
                'class'         => 'width-1-5',
                'priority'      => 60
            ),
            $details['details_2']['id'] => array(
                'label'         => $details['details_2']['label'],
                'key'           => '_details_2',
                'data'          => $details['details_2']['data'],
                'type'          => 'select',
                'data_compare'  => '>=',
                'class'         => 'width-1-5',
                'priority'      => 70
            )           
        );
`
```

Example on keyword I will set a value HOME Instead showing its label.

Thank you!

Comment: You have copied your code in twice. Remove one of the examples.

Comment: @alexi2 got it thankyou :)

Comment: The default value on search form? placeholder?

Comment: @RajendranNadar  a value attribute not a placeholder.

Comment: Ok you want to add a value to the search input only if it is empty? or depending upon the page? I didn't understand when to add value attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I got it now I should add 'default'  =>  'Myvalue',

example

```
'keyword' => array(
                'label'         => __( 'Keyword or Listing ID', 'wpcasa' ) . '&hellip;',
                'type'          => 'text',
                'class'         => 'width-3-4',
                'default'       => 'HELLO',
                'priority'      => 10
            ),
```

Thanks for the help/advice!